# function to add odd number and even number to an array with conditions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve this problem, but my code does not work properly so here is the problem that I'm trying to solve.

> Write a function addingAllTheWeirdStuff which adds the sum of all the
> odd numbers in array2  to each element under 10 in array1. Similarly,
> addingAllTheWeirdStuff should also add the sum  of all the even
> numbers in array2 to those elements over 10 in array1.
>
> If any element in array2 is greater than 20, add 1 to every
> element in array1.

And here is my code.

```
function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2) {
  let arr1_2 = []
  let totalOds = 0
  let totalEvens = 0

  // suming th odds numbers in array2 
  totalOds = array2.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr % 2 !== 0 ? acc += curr : null, acc), 0)
  
  // suming th even numbers in array2
  totalEvens = array2.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr % 2 === 0 ? acc += curr : null, acc), 0)

  // adding the total to odd number in array1
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    let arods = array1[i]
    if (arods % 2 !== 0 && arods < 10) {
      arods += totalOds
      arr1_2.push(arods)
    }
  }

  // adding the total to even numbers in array1
  for (let j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
    let areven = array1[j]
    if (areven % 2 === 0 && areven > 10) {
      areven += totalEvens
      arr1_2.push(areven)
    }
  }
  return arr1_2
}

console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
// expected log [10, 12, 14, 23, 21]
console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 22]));
// expected log [11, 13, 15, 46, 44, 11]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By having a little hole for values equal `10`, according to the specs:

> ... adds the sum of all the odd numbers in array2 to each element **under 10** in array1. Similarly, addingAllTheWeirdStuff should also add the sum of all the even numbers in array2 to those elements **over 10** in array1. [**bold** by NS]

Take a first iteration for getting a bonus for a greater value and sum even and odd values.

Later return a new array with even/odd or offset.

```js
function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2) {
    let offset = false,
        even = 0,
        odd = 0;
        
    for (const value of array2) {
        if (value > 20) offset = true;
        if (value % 2) odd += value; else even += value;
    }
    even += offset;
    odd += offset;
    return array1.map(v => v + (v < 10 ? odd : v > 10 ? even : offset));
}

console.log(...addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // [10, 12, 14, 23, 21]
console.log(...addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 22])); // [11, 13, 15, 46, 44, 11]
console.log(...addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 29, 3, 4, 5, 22])); // [40, 42, 44, 44, 42, 40]
```

Comment: Hi Nina,

your code is so very clean but check this test, please.

console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 29, 3, 4, 5, 22]));
// should return [40, 42, 44, 44, 42, 40]

expected [ 41, 43, 45, 45, 43, 41 ] to deeply equal [ 40, 42, 44, 44, 42, 40 ]

TypeError: array2 is not iterable

Comment: JUST WOW.......

Comment: @Th1, now `offset` is a boolean. please see edit.

Comment: @nina-scholz    it works perfectly now perfekt

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the sums of odd and even numbers your code adds it individually, I've made necessary changes to the code and it shall work

```js
function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2) {
  let totalOdds = 0;
  let totalEvens = 0;
  let addedOne = false

  // Calculate the sum of odd and even numbers in array2
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      totalOdds += array2[i];
    } else if (array2[i] % 2 === 0) {
      totalEvens += array2[i];
    }

    if (array2[i] > 20 && !addedOne) {
      for (let j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
        array1[j] += 1;
      }
      addedOne = true
    }
  }

  // Add the sums to elements in array1 as per the rules
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] < 10) {
      result.push(array1[i] + totalOdds);
    } else if (array1[i] > 10) {
      result.push(array1[i] + totalEvens);
    } else {
      result.push(array1[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
// Expected output: [10, 12, 14, 23, 21]
console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 22]));
// Expected output: [11, 13, 15, 23, 21, 11]
```

Comment: Hi Kushagra,
Thank you for your replying, your code is working except the last condition which is " If any element in array2 is greater than 20, add 1 to every element in array1." it does not work for this condition

Comment: It shall work may I know what is getting logged

Comment: Hi Kushagra, 
check this console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 29, 3, 4, 5, 22]));

Comment: I am getting `[41, 43, 45, 45, 43, 41]` which is the same output coming from any other code

Comment: expected [ 41, 43, 45, 45, 43, 41 ]       
to deeply equal [ 40, 42, 44, 44, 42, 40 ]

Comment: `console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 29, 3, 4, 5, 22]))`

Comment: Found the issue, you need it to add the number 1 once into the array but the current code adds it as many times as the number is greater than 20, I've updated my code and it shall work now

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to you code, and add some comments to it. Hope this would help.

In addtion. Try these arguments

- array1 = [1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1]
- array2 = [1, 26, 33, 42, 5, 22]

what happens is

- 1 + 4 = 5 + 39
- 3 + 4 = 7 + 39
- 5 + 4 = 9 + 39
- 17 + 4 = 21 + 90
- 15 + 4 = 19 + 90
- 1 + 4 = 5 + 39

expected output -> [44, 46, 48, 111, 109, 44]

```js
function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2) {
    const arr1 = [...array1];
    const arr2 = [...array2];

    let oddsTotal, evensTotal;
    const odds = [],
        evens = [],
        lessThan10Indexes = [],
        lessThan20NotLessThan10Indexes = [];

    // A.   group the item that are greater than 10 but not greater than 20
    //      and all the items that are greater that 20
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] <= 10) {
            lessThan10Indexes.push(i);
        } else if (arr1[i] < 20 && arr1[i] > 10) {
            lessThan20NotLessThan10Indexes.push(i);
        }

        // B. group the odds
        if (arr2[i] % 2) {
            odds.push(arr2[i]);
        }

        // C. group the evens
        if (!(arr2[i] % 2)) {
            evens.push(arr2[i]);
        }
    }

    // D. set the total of the odds and evens
    oddsTotal = odds.length ? odds.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc += curr)) : 0;
    evensTotal = evens.length ? evens.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc += curr)) : 0;

    // E. if there are any items that are greater that 20 in arr2, it will add 1 to each items in arr1
    for (let n = 0; n < arr2.length; n++) {
        if (arr2[n] > 20) {
            for (let m = 0; m < arr1.length; m++) {
                arr1[m] += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // F. loop through arr1
    for (let n = 0; n < arr1.length; n++) {
        // F.1. add the sum of the odds to each items in arr1 that are less than 10
        for (let k = 0; k < lessThan10Indexes.length; k++) {
            if (lessThan10Indexes[k] == n) {
                arr1[n] += oddsTotal;
            }
        }
        // F.2. add the sum of the evens to each items in arr1 that are greater than 10
        for (let l = 0; l < lessThan20NotLessThan10Indexes.length; l++) {
            if(lessThan20NotLessThan10Indexes[l] == n){
                arr1[n] += evensTotal;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return arr1;
}

console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 22]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2) {

  const sums = Object.values(array2.reduce((acc, val) => {
  
    const key = val % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
    acc[key] += val;
    return acc;
    
  }, { even: 0, odd: 0 }));

  return array1.map((num, index) => {
    num = num < 10 ? num + sums[1] : num > 10 ? num + sums[0] : num;
    return array2.some(num => num > 20) ? num + 1 : num;
  });
}

console.log(...addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
// expected log [10, 12, 14, 23, 21]
console.log(...addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 22]))
// expected log [11, 13, 15, 46, 44, 11]
console.log(...addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 29, 3, 4, 5, 22]))
// should return [40, 42, 44, 44, 42, 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

@nina-scholz
@kushagra-srivastava

Thank you **so much** for your code and reply

I modified my code like this

```
function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(arr1, arr2) {
  let sumOdd = 0
  let sumEven = 0
  let greaterThan20 = false

  //filtering the odd numbers and the even numbers and add  to variables
  arr2.reduce((ac, cur) => (ac = (cur % 2 !== 0 ? sumOdd += cur : sumEven += cur), ac), 0)

  //checking if elements in arr2 has greater than 20
  arr2.some(a => a > 20 ? greaterThan20 = true : greaterThan20 = false)

  //looping through arr1
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] < 10) {
      arr1[i] += sumOdd  // adding sum to odd numbers in arr1
    } else if (arr1[i] > 10) {
      arr1[i] += sumEven  // adding sum toeven number in arr1
    }
    if (greaterThan20)
      arr1[i] += 1  // adding 1 to every element in arr1 because arr2 has element over 20
  }
  return arr1
}

console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
// expected log [10, 12, 14, 23, 21]
console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 22]))
// expected log [11, 13, 15, 46, 44, 11]
console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 29, 3, 4, 5, 22]))
// should return [40, 42, 44, 44, 42, 40]
```